# WordPress Excerpt - Javascript - PHP - Ajax?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, responsive-design

I've created this script inside my home.php file for my WordPress theme to calculate the value of a `div` width in relation with a number (1.408). This operation give me the result (inside `$chars` variable) to establish number of characters to use in the excerpt for Responsive Design. If the `div` is larger or thinner, I'll have a different number of characters for my WordPress Excerpt.

This is the code I've published on HOME.PHP. Javascript followed by PHP code for excerpt.
I know javascript variable inside PHP is impossible without Ajax (reading on other forums), but I cannot understand what exactly to do. I am not so good with code. Be clear please and if possible with some examples!

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var $myDiv = jQuery('#last_post_img_text');
var $results = jQuery('#results');
var $chars = jQuery( $myDiv.outerWidth()/1.408 );
</script>       

<?php new_excerpt( $chars ); ?>
```

Comment: So what exactly are you asking?

Comment: How to let this variable $chars working inside the PHP code. I think Ajax is necessary to do it, but don't know how. Or, if possible to know how to have DIV width using PHP (so, without Javascript, maybe I could jump over the problem?)

Comment: You must understand, that JS is working on client side, while php is on server side. So the php file is rendering a source of a page, which is then rendered in users browser. Then You access with JS to already rendered elements. 

If You want instead to load a content, check its lenght and then cut it out, You need .ajax load a php file with a variable that will let php file return more or less of "characters".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest an approach:
Load a page, check conteiner element width and height, then use $.ajax to load elements content, and send some kind of a variable to decide how many characters to use.
If You would like to do it in WordPress way, read about:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_$handlename', 'function_to_run');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_$handlename', 'function_to_run');
```

that will reposnd to Yours ajax request.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'theme_js', get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/js/jquery-theme.js', array('jquery'), THEME_VERSION, false );
$protocol = isset( $_SERVER["HTTPS"] ) ? 'https://' : 'http://';
$params = array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php', $protocol )  );
wp_localize_script( 'theme_js', 'theme_js', $params );
```

this might come handy, if You dont know how to send wp-ajax.php localisation to jQuery $.ajax request.

Comment: If You like an answer, vote it up and mark as correct. It helps community grow :).

Answer (score 0):

Reloading the comments with Ajax seems like a bad decision. Why would you want to keep reloading content that doesn't really change. I think your best bet is to use a jQuery plugin.

One that seems to do what you want is http://www.bramstein.com/projects/text-overflow/.

Alternatively you can check out the CSS3 property 'text-overflow' (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp).

Comment: And what question have to do with comments?

Comment: Oops my bad, you're right. I meant to say excerpt of course! Point is that if you have a responsive design it is possible that the form factor of the page changes multiple times. Example: I wouldn't want to reload the content if I rescale my browser but manipulate it instead.